# Focus ring opacity not working with arbitrary value

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind 3. I have applied a ring on focus to my text input with an arbitrary color like this:

```
<input type="text" className="focus:ring focus:ring-[rgba(0, 244, 0)]" />
```

This works fine, however after I try applying an opacity to this ring it fails:

```
<input type="text" className="focus:ring focus:ring-[rgba(0, 244, 0)] focus:ring-opacity-30" />
```

This opacity works fine if I don't use an arbitrary color like this:

```
<input type="text" className="focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-30" />
```

Any ideas how to make `ring-opacity` work with arbitrary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example:

```
<input type="text" className="focus:ring focus:ring-[rgba(0, 244, 0)]" />
```

I expect your arbitrary value is being ignored. The color you see (a light blue I suspect) is coming from the default of `focus:ring`.

Tailwind arbitrary values don't work with rgb or rgba values, [this](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/5006#issuecomment-882229133) issue on Github exposed it and this [pull](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/5239) was supposed to fix it but you can still see the behavior on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Tv8lkLkkLn) quite clearly, there is no generated class when using arbitrary rgb values (if there were a tiny color swatch would appear next to the class).

For now the safest path is to use hex colors instead of rgb or rgba.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind [in this issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7521#issuecomment-1044764301). Classes cannot have spaces per [the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace). So the Tailwind Play example from above does work with whitespace extracted or replaced with underscores https://play.tailwindcss.com/xpPrMf5bO8.

Comment: Oh yes it is a blueish color. Thanks for this! I will keep watching that issue to see when they land. Thanks very much! I learned a bunch from your post, really appreciate the Tailwind Play too.

Comment: Happy to help, I don't think they will be fixing it on that issue. They closed it like it was solved, but it looks like that's not the case.

Comment: Oh you're right, I'll post a comment there linking to our post here to tell them about it.

Comment: That comment might escape their view, I created an issue, way way thanks for such a great deep dive,  I as able to share exactly this post over there - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7521

Comment: Oh interesting situation, the spaces in the rgba messed up the above. The question above was simplification of my actual situation. So I then compared to my situation and it seems like its a css var situation, I updated the tailplay and comment here - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7521#issuecomment-1044841976

Comment: Wow! I'm going to edit my answer to the RGB part to reference the handling whitespace docs for anyone who stumbles across this. But for the vars and extracting the channels and adding the opacity as a var... that's definitely not something from the docs I would have connected with arbitrary values, great work!

Comment: Thank you man all cuz of your stuff there I was able to ask this and get answers. His channel only example is super interesting - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7521#issuecomment-1044936537 - thanks for elaborating on that with the underscores etc.